# Apache2. How to work with <Location> and <Directory> together?

Tags: configuration, apache2, virtualhost, apache

I'm trying to set specified configuration for location in my apache configuration.
But it isn't working for me.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerName site.ru
        DocumentRoot /storage/htdocs

        <Directory />
                Header add Dir 1
        </Directory>

        <Location ~ "api">
                Header add Api 1
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to extend my directory section with my api section.
But I can't see "Api: 1" in headers list.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The path in the `<Directory>` directive must match your `DocumentRoot`. It's relative to the filesystem, not the document root.